# redis, socket.io - problem connecting to a Redis server on the local machine using the default port

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel, redis, socket.io

I want to setup the real-time web-app with Laravel and using socket.io, redis, node server.
Here is my server.js code:

```
var app = require('express')();

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8888');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});

var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server, {
    cors: { origin: '*' },
});

var redis = require('redis');

server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('hel');
});

io.on('connection', async function (socket) {
    console.log('client connected');

    var redisClient = redis.createClient({
        legacyMode: true,
    });

    await redisClient.connect().catch(console.error);

    redisClient.subscribe('message');
    redisClient.on('message', function (channel, data) {
        console.log('message received');
        socket.emit(channel, data);
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        redisClient.quit();
    });
});
```

In my controller, I use Redis as following code, this function effect is when I add a post (Post is 'BaiDang' in my mother language), Redis will publish and I can notification real-time in browser:

```
public function store(Request $request, BaiDang $baiDang)
    {
        try {
            $baiDang->create($request->all());
            if ($request->hasFile('files')) {
                foreach ($request->file('files') as $file) {
                    $name = time() . rand(1, 100) . Str::random(40) . '.' . $file->extension();
                    Storage::putFileAs('files', $file, $name);

                    $fileData['bai_dang_id'] = DB::table('bai_dang')->max('id');
                    $fileData['link'] = 'files/' . $name;

                    FileBaiDang::create($fileData);
                }
            }
            Redis::connection();
            Redis::publish('message', json_encode($request->all()));
            return $this->success($baiDang, 201, 'Created');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            //catch exception
            echo 'Message: ' . $e->getMessage();
            return $this->error(400, 'Lỗi server update không thành công');
        }
    }
```

I have another client-file which name is socket.io.js:

```
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

const socket_host = '127.0.0.1';
const socket_port = '3000';
const socket = io(socket_host + ':' + socket_port);

socket.on('message', (data) => {
    console.log('aaahhahaahah');
});
```

And I import this file below in app.js:
`import './socket.io';`

At the time I run node server by the cmd 'node server', when client connected, it's have an erorr:

```
client connected
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:6379
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1300:16) {
  errno: -4078,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '::1',
  port: 6379
}
```

Please, anyone help me...

By the way, I asked GPT and have a lot of way to fix, but fail. If you say that I check if I run redis server, using a right config host and port, etc... I try all of that...haizz